# Finite State Transducers in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, state-machine, transducer

I've been wondering if there is a way to define and work with [finite state transducers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer) in Haskell in an idiomatic way.

You can approach FSTs as *generators* (it generates an output of type {x1,x2}), or as *recognizers* (given an input of type {x1,x2} it recognizes it if it belongs to the rational relation), or as *translators* (given an input tape, it translates it into an output tape). Would the representation change depending on the approach?

Would it also be possible to model a FST in a way that you can produce one by specifying rewriting rules? E.g creating a DSL to model rewriting rules, and then creating a function `createFST :: [Rule] -> FST`.

The closest I could find is Kmett, Bjarnason and Cough's `machines` library:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines

But I can't seem to realize how to model a FST with a `Machine`. I'd suppose that the correct way of doing it would be similar to how they define Moore and Mealy machines: define a FST as a different entity, but provide an instance of `Automaton` to be able to use it as a machine.

I found some other options too, but they define it in a straightforward way (like in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fst ). That doesn't convince me much, as I wonder if there's a better way to do so idiomatically using the strengths of Haskell's type system (like how Moore and Mealy machines are defined in the `machines` library).

Comment: This question needs editing to be on-topic for StackOverflow. Explicitly asking for a library or resource recommendation is off-topic, but describing a specific problem and soliciting solutions (which may very well involve libraries) is acceptable. Asking the *best* way to do something is usually too broad or opinion-based. Asking for *a* way to do something still results in high quality answers, but with less opinionated discussion of their merits.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A [`Mealy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.4.1/docs/Data-Machine-Mealy.html) machine alternately reads an `a` from a stream of inputs `a` and outputs a `b` to a stream of outputs. It reads first and then outputs once after each read.

```
newtype Mealy a b = Mealy { runMealy :: a -> (b, Mealy a b) }
```

A [`Moore`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.4.1/docs/Data-Machine-Moore.html) machine alternately outputs a `b` to a stream of outputs and reads an input `a` from a stream of inputs. It starts with an output of `b` and then reads once after each output.

```
data Moore a b = Moore b (a -> Moore a b)
```

An FST either reads from it's input, writes to its output, or stops. It can read as many times in a row as it wants or write as many times in a row as it wants.

```
data FST a b
    = Read  (a -> FST a b)
    | Write (b,   FST a b)
    | Stop
```

The equivalent of an `FST` from machines is [`Process`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.4.1/docs/Data-Machine-Process.html#t:Process). It's definition is a little spread out. To simplify the discussion we are going to forget about `Process` for now and explore it from the inside-out.

#### The base functor

To describe what a `Process` is, we're going to first notice a pattern in all three machines so far. Each of them recursively refers to itself for "what to do next". We are going to replace "what to do next" with any type `next`. The `Mealy` machine, while mapping an input to an output, also provides the `next` machine to run.

```
newtype MealyF a b next = MealyF { runMealyF :: a -> (b, next) }
```

The `Moore` machine, after outputting and requesting an input, figures out the `next` machine to run.

```
data MooreF a b next = MooreF b (a -> next)
```

We can write the `FST` the same way. When we `Read` from the input we'll figure out what to do `next` depending on the input. When we `Write` to the output we'll also provide what to do `next` after outputting. When we `Stop` there's nothing to do next.

```
data FSTF a b next
    = Read  (a -> next)
    | Write (b,   next)
    | Stop
```

This pattern of eliminating explicit recursion shows up repeatedly in Haskell code, and is usually called a "base functor". In the machines package the base functor is [`Step`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.4.1/docs/Data-Machine-Type.html#t:Step). Compared to our code, `Step` has renamed the type variable for the output to `o`, what to do next to `r`, reading to `Await`, and writing to `Yield`.

```
data Step k o r
  = forall t. Await (t -> r) (k t) r
  | Yield o r
  | Stop
```

`Await`ing is a little more complicated than `Read` because a [`Machine`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.4.1/docs/Data-Machine-Type.html#t:Machine) can read from multiple sources. For `Process`es that can only read from a single source, `k` is [`Is`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.4.1/docs/Data-Machine-Is.html) applied to a specific type, which is a proof the second type `Is` the first type. For a `Process` reading inputs `a`, `k` will be `Is a`.

```
data Step (Is a) o r
  = forall t. Await (t -> r) (Is a t) r
  | Yield o r
  | Stop
```

The existential quantification `forall t.` is an [implementation detail for dealing with `Source`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17282019/414413). After witnessing that `a ~ t` this becomes.

```
data Step (Is a) o r
  = forall t ~ a. Await (t -> r) Refl r
  | Yield o r
  | Stop
```

If we unify `t` with `a` and remove the `Refl` constructor which is always the same, this looks like our `FSTF`.

```
data Step (Is a) o r
  = Await (a -> r) r
  | Yield  o    r
  | Stop
```

The extra `r` for what to do next in `Await` is what to do next when there's no more input.

#### The machine transformer `MachineT`

The machine transformer, [`MachineT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.4.1/docs/Data-Machine-Type.html#t:MachineT), makes `Step` look almost like our `FST`. It says, "A machine operating over some monad `m` is what to do in that monad to get the next `Step`. The `next` thing to do after each step is another `MachineT`."

```
newtype MachineT m k o = MachineT { runMachineT :: m (Step k o (MachineT m k o)) }
```

Overall, specialized for our types, this looks like

```
newtype MachineT m (Is a) o = 
    MachineT m (
        Await (a -> MachineT m (Is a) o) (MachineT m (Is a) o)
      | Yield  o   (MachineT m (Is a) o)
      | Stop
    )
```

`Machine` is a pure `MachineT`.

```
type Machine k o = forall m. Monad m => MachineT m k o
```

Universal quantification over all `Monad`s `m` is another way of saying a computation doesn't need anything from an underlying `Monad`. This can be seen by substituting [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) for `m`.

```
type Machine k o = 
    MachineT Identity (
        Await (a -> MachineT Identity k o) (MachineT Identity k o)
      | Yield  o   (MachineT Identity k o)
      | Stop
    )
```

#### Processes

A `Process` or `ProcessT` is a `Machine` or `MachineT` that only reads a single type of input `a`, `Is a`.

```
type Process    a b = Machine    (Is a) b
type ProcessT m a b = MachineT m (Is a) b
```

A `Process` has the following structure after removing all the intermediate constructors that are always the same. This structure is exactly the same as our `FST`, except it has an added "what to do next" in the case that there's no more input.

```
type Process a b =
    Await (a -> Process a b) (Process a b)
  | Yield  b   (Process a b)
  | Stop
```

The `ProcessT` variant has an `m` wrapped around it so that it can act in the monad at each step.

`Process` models state transducers.

Comment: Fantastic `machines` tutorial, thanks. I've been meaning to try to understand that library for quite some time. I wonder if there is a way to attach this discussion to the official documentation somehow.

Comment: Awesome. With Moore and Mealy machines in the `machines` library, you can create a machine by unfolding over explicit state using `unfoldMoore` or `unfoldMealy`. These functions model the transition functions that define a Moore/Mealy machine, so you can still use them to construct a machine in the traditional way (defining the states, then defining the transition and output function). Is there a similar function that can be created for FSTs (i.e `Process`)?

Comment: @gonzaw That would make a good follow up question. This question was about how to model finite state machines in Haskell, that question would be about how to specifically `unfold` a `Process` using the machines library. The question will be better if you can provide a specific problem, like how to unfold a `Process` from `data State = RepeatNext Word8 | SayAgain Word8 Word8` and `step (RepeatNext n) = Await (x -> SayAgain n x) Stop; step (SayAgain 0 _) = Await (n -> RepeatNext n) Stop; step (SayAgain n x) = Yield x (SayAgain (n-1) x)`

Comment: Ok. I'll first try toying around with `Process` to try and see if I can figure it out. If not I'll make a follow up question. I'll mark this as answered then.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this models finite state transducers in Haskell, but rather (potentially infinite) state transducers. For instance, finite state transducers can be inverted. How would one invert an FST by this definition? I don't think it's possible.