# when to use CPS vs codensity vs reflection without remorse in Haskell

Tags: haskell, reflection, monads, continuations, free-monad

Are there any rules of thumb for when to use **continuation-passing style** vs **codensity** vs **reflection without remorse** when creating monads in Haskell?

As an example, I'm going to use a simple coroutine monad. If you've never seen this before, you might want to check out the "Coroutine Pipelines" article in [Monad.Reader Issue 19](https://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/issue19.pdf) or the [pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) library.  The full code for the following examples can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/cdepillabout/cps-vs-codensity-vs-reflection-without-remorse).

1. **Normal**

   This is just a normal monad defined as a datatype:

   ```
   data FooM i o a
     = Await (i -> FooM i o a)
     | Yield o (FooM i o a)
     | Done a
   ```

   This style is used extensively thorought the Haskell ecosystem.  One example of this style is the [`Proxy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.4/docs/Pipes.html#t:Proxy) data type from `pipes`.
2. **Continuation-Passing Style (CPS)**

   This is similar to the **normal** style, but each data constructor has become an argument to a continuation:

   ```
   newtype FooCPS i o a = FooCPS
     { runFooCPS
         :: forall r.
            ((i -> FooCPS i o a) -> r)
         -> (o -> FooCPS i o a -> r)
         -> (a -> r)
         -> r
     }
   ```

   This style is used in both [attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.1.0/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Internal-Types.html#t:Parser) and [parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t:ParsecT).
3. **Codensity**

   This style uses a [codensity monad transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Codensity.html#t:Codensity) wrapped around a monad defined in the **normal** style.  This gives O(1) left-associative bind.

   The codensity monad transformer looks like the following:

   ```
   newtype Codensity m a = Codensity
     { runCodensity :: forall b. (a -> m b) -> m b
     }
   ```

   Our actual monad could be defined as a newtype using the `Codensity` transformer.  Notice how `FooCodensity` is using `FooM` internally.

   ```
   newtype FooCodensity i o a = FooCodensity
     { runFooCodensity :: Codensity (FooM i o) a
     }
   ```

   This style is used by [conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) in the [`ConduitM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.11/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t:ConduitM) type.
4. **Reflection without Remorse**

   This is the style discussed in the paper [Reflection without Remorse](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/zseq.pdf).

   This is similar to the **normal** style, but recursive calls have become a data structure with O(1) append and amortized O(1) uncons.  This gives O(1) left-associative bind and monadic-reflection to the `FooRWR` monad:

   ```
   data FooRWR i o a
     = AwaitRWR (forall x. i -> FooExplicit i o x a)
     | YieldRWR  o (forall x. FooExplicit i o x a)
     | DoneRWR a
   ```

   The `FooExplicit` type is defined as the following:

   ```
   type FooExplicit i o = FTCQueue (FooRWR i o)
   ```

   `FTCQueue` is a data structure with O(1) append and amortized O(1) uncons.

   This style is used by the [freer-effects](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer-effects-0.3.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Freer-Internal.html#t:Eff) and [extensible](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extensible-0.4.2/docs/Data-Extensible-Effect.html) packages.  It is available as a standalone library in [monad-skeleton](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-skeleton-0.1.3.2/docs/Control-Monad-Skeleton.html#t:Spine).

---

When should **normal** vs **CPS** vs **codensity** vs **reflection without remorse** be used?  I imagine a hard and fast answer would require benchmarking a given monad and application, but are there *any rules of thumb*?

From my own research, I've come across the following ideas/comments:

- **CPS** can be faster than **normal** style because you may not have to do case-analysis.  Although the actual speedup may vary based on how the code is compiled by GHC.  **Codensity** and **reflection without remorse** have some overhead.

  Gabriel Gonzalez (the author of `pipes`) writes about how he sticks with **normal** style for `pipes` in both [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/23m4bs/i_added_a_coroutine_example_to_the_wiki_did_i/) and this [issue](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Pipes-Library/issues/100) on Github.

  Bryan O'Sullivan (the author of `attoparsec`) writes about how changing `attoparsec` from **normal** style to **CPS** gave a [factor of 8 speedup](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2011/02/25/cps-is-great-cps-is-terrible/).  Some of the comments on that post also talk about **normal** style vs **CPS**.
- If you need deep left associative binds, **normal** style and **CPS** end up with quadratic runtime.

  Here is an example from the "Reflection without Remorse" paper that will exhibit quadratic runtime.

  ```
  data It i a = Get (i -> It i a) | Done a

  sumInput :: Int -> It Int Int
  sumInput n = Get (foldl (>=>) return (replicate (n - 1) f))
    where
      f x = get >>= return . (+ x)
  ```

  If `sumInput` is rewritten with **codensity** or **reflection without remorse**, it will run perfectly fast.

  If your application has deep left-associative binds, you should probably be using **codensity** or **reflection without remorse**.

  Michael Snoyman (author of `conduit`) talks about this in a blog post about [speeding up](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2014/08/iap-speeding-up-conduit#continuation-passing-style--church-encoding--codensity) `conduit`.

  The `pipes` library [used to provide](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-3.3.0/docs/Control-Proxy-Trans-Codensity.html) a codensity transformer.
- **CPS** and **codensity** don't support O(1) reflection.

  Here is a function that requires monadic reflection.  This example is adapted from the "Reflection without Remorse" paper:

  ```
  data It i a = Get (i -> It i a) | Done a

  par :: It i a -> It i b -> It i (It i a, It i b)
  par l r
    | Done <- l = Done (l, r)
    | Done <- r = Done (l, r)
    | Get f <- l, Get g <- r = Get Done >>= \x -> par (f x) (g x)
  ```

  This method can't be written in the **CPS** or **codensity** style without first converting back to **normal** style.  The **reflection without remorse** style does not have this problem.

  If you need monadic reflection, you should probably be using **normal** style or **reflection without remorse**.
- **Reflection without remorse** adds some overhead, but it is the only style that gives both O(1) left-associative bind and reflection.

*bonus question*: A similar question could be asked about [`Free`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.3/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html#t:Free) (**normal** style) vs [`F`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.3/docs/Control-Monad-Free-Church.html#t:F) (**CPS**) from the [free](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) package.  When should `Free` be used?  When should `F` be used?

Comment: I posted this question to reddit's /r/haskell: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6qn4y0/when_to_use_cps_vs_codensity_vs_reflection/

Comment: It should be noted that in CPS, you usually replace all occurrences of `FooCPS i o a` with `r` (depending on the performance you want).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This problem can be broken into two pieces, how you represent the data type and how you compose them together.

#### Data types

The styles you listed use only 2 styles of data types, the "normal" style and the continuation passing style. They differ in which objects are chosen as the primitives of the language.

In the normal style data types and their constructors are chosen as primitive. The data types are sums (having multiple constructors) of products (holding multiple values)

```
data Sum a b = Left a | Right b
data Product a b = Product a b
```

The main objects of the language are these data types and functions; the functions deconstruct the data to look inside it and see what it does.

```
either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Sum a b -> c
either l _ (Left a)  = l a
either _ r (Right b) = r b

uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> Product a b -> c
uncurry f (Product a b) = f a b
```

You can make an equivalent language where universally quantified types are treated as primitive instead of data types. In this case you can define the data types in terms of universal quantification. Sums are represented by their `either` function, universally quantified over the return type. Products are represented by their `uncurry` function, universally quantified over the return type. The need for a language extension (`RankNTypes`) to represent data types this way hints at why you'd call the first style "normal".

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype Product a b = Product (forall r. (a -> b -> r) -> r)

product :: a -> b -> Product a b
product a b = Product (\f -> f a b)

uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> Product a b -> c
uncurry both (Product f) = f both

newtype Sum a b = Sum (forall r. (a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r)

left :: a -> Sum a b
left a = Sum (\l r -> l a)

right :: b -> Sum a b
right b = Sum (\l r -> r b)

either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Sum a b -> c
either l r (Sum f) = f l r
```

This gives rise to one of the main differences between the two styles. In the universally quantified style there aren't any constructors. All of the structure of the data must be stored in closures to functions, which is exactly where the replacements for constructors `left`, `right`, and `product` put it. In the universally quantified style you can't construct any unnecessary intermediate objects; no object exists for you to construct. You can still construct unnecessary intermediate closures. At the very least you'll trick the profiler into telling you that you don't have a bunch of objects hanging around.

Your `FooM` data type, repeated here, can also be represented in continuation passing style.

```
data FooM i o a
  = Await (i -> FooM i o a)
  | Yield o (FooM i o a)
  | Done a
```

It will be represented by its `matchFoo` function, which I've defined.

```
matchFoo :: ((i -> FooM i o a) -> r) -> (o -> FooM i o a -> r) -> (a -> r) -> r
matchFoo a _ _ (Await f) = a f
matchFoo _ y _ (Yield o next) = y o next
matchFoo _ _ d (Done a) = d a
```

The universally quantified `FooM` identifies a `FooM` with its `matchFoo` function, universally qualified over its return type.

```
newtype FooCPS i o a = FooCPS
  { runFooCPS
      :: forall r.
         ((i -> FooCPS i o a) -> r)
      -> (o -> FooCPS i o a -> r)
      -> (a -> r)
      -> r
  }

await :: (i -> FooCPS i o a) -> FooCPS i o a
await f = FooCPS (\a _ _ -> a f)

yield :: o -> FooCPS i o a -> FooCPS i o a
yield o next = FooCPS (\_ y _ -> y o next)

done :: a -> FooCPS i o a
done a = FooCPS (\_ _ d -> d a)
```

#### Breaking the problem in 2

To use the same data type for all the ways of composing them back together we're going to replace `FooM` with its base functor. The base functor is the normal data type with recursions replaced by a type variable.

```
data FooF i o a next
  = Await (i -> next)
  | Yield o next
  | Done a
    deriving (Functor)
```

You can equivalently define a base functor in continuation passing style.

```
newtype FooFCPS i o a next = FooFCPS
  { runFooCPS
      :: forall r.
         ((i -> next) -> r)
      -> (o -> next -> r)
      -> (a -> r)
      -> r
  }
  deriving (Functor)
```

#### Composing them back together

1. **Normal**

We can immediately recover `FooM` by defining

```
newtype FooM i o a = FooM (FooF i o a (FooM i o a))
```

If you've already defined the [fixed point of a functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#t:Fix):

```
newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
```

Then `FooM` can be recovered by

```
newtype FooM i o a = FooM (Fix (FooF i o a))
```

2. **Continuation Passing Style**

Continuation passing style can be immediately recovered from the universally quantified `FooFCPS`

```
newtype FooCPS i o a = FooCPS (Fix (FooFCPS i o a))
```

3. **Codensity**

The codensity transformer works with either `FooM` or `FooCPS`.

4. **Reflection without Remorse**

We can define reflection without remorse in terms of base functors without reproducing the data type `FooM` in `FooRWR`.

```
newtype RWR f a = RWR { runRWR :: f (RWRExplicit f a) }

newtype RWRExplicit f a = RWRExplicit (forall x. FTCQueue (RWR f) x a)
```

And then recover `FooRWR` with

```
newtype FooRWR i o a = FooRWR {runFooRWR :: RWR (FooF i o a) a}
```

#### Bonus observations

**Free**

Both `Free` and `F` will work with either of the base functors `FooF` or `FooFCPS`.

**Monad Transformers**

The base functor can also be used to build a monad transformer. There's a [detailed discussion of building the `MachineT` transformer (which is closely related to `FooM`) in this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997155/finite-state-transducers-in-haskell).

---

The claim that `par` can't be written in CPS without first converting back to normal style needs some qualification, since all data types can be replaced with universally quantified continuation-passing style types.

Comment: This is a really nice answer.  It shows just how similar normal style and CPS are.  I also like the abstraction over `FooF` and `FooFCPS` by using `Fix`.  However, I'm not really sure it answers my question of **when** to use CPS vs codensity vs reflection without remorse.  I'm guess I'm mostly asking a performance question, which is hard to answer without specifics, but it would be interesting if there were any rules of thumb for when to use which style.

Comment: Am I incorrect about the statement about `par`?  I just looked back throught the "Reflection without Remorse" paper and they talk about `par` in section 6.1.  They specifically mention that `par` can't be written in the codensity style without first converting back to the normal style, but they don't say anything about CPS.  I was under the impression that monadic-reflection is impossible when writing CPS code unless you convert back to a normal style.

Comment: You can also define `Fix` via `newtype Fix f = Product (forall r. (f r -> r) -> r)`. Then you don't even need to use recursion.